# How do I turn on sustain on Casio CT-X9000IN keyboard without a sustain pedal?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-pedals, sustain

Casio CT-X5000 has sustain button but CT-X9000IN does not though both are same keyboard.
So how do I turn on sustain on CT-X9000IN without a sustain pedal?

Comment: look for: *How to get sustain on keyboard piano without buying a sustain pedal!*

Comment: Why would you not want to use a pedal? This keyboard has 2 pedal jack inputs on the back.

Answer (score -1):

I have made the experience that the contact of a jack input has the same effect. The problem will be plugging  the jack in and out while playing. But here seems to be a solution.

[Sustain without Pedal](https://youtu.be/c81YVl8mUBc)

Comment: The link doesn't work! But why would anyone want to use anything except a pedal..?

Comment: I guess the point is that on a non-Indian model of the same keyboard there's a _button_ you can press to activate sustain, if you don't have a sustain pedal. But on the INdian version, the button is missing or assigned to a different purpose. So the OP is asking, how to do a pedal-less sustain on the indian model which doesn't have the button. Maybe by sendind a MIDI control change message? Maybe reading the manual or contacting customer support could help.

Comment: Surely a switch soldered to a 6.5 Jack would be a bit less "hacky" ;)

Answer (score -2):

Get a simple switch - a bell push will do - and connect it to a jack plug.  Put it in the pedal jack.   You could even contrive to work it with your foot!